# Angular JS with PHP with Input field and Submit Button

Tags: php, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have UI with Input field and Submit Button,And After Entering Number in field and clicking on Submit Button. I want this to go to first.php file and second.php depends on the first.php response. At the end I want to show to value from second.php, Can you please help me on this.

And I am using AngularJS with PHP  And I am creating 2 functions with in one controller and calling 2 functions at time by clicking on button Can you please suggest me on the approach?

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
    <div ng-controller="get_controller">
        <input type="text" ng-model="accountnumber" name="accountnumber" class="form-control search-query" placeholder="Enter Account Number">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="submit" ng-click="sendAccountNumber();geValues()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="get_controller">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-repeat="list in personDetails">{{list.Name}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="features" ng-repeat="list in personDetails">{{list.Location}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</html>
```

**AngularJS**

```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngTable"]);
app.controller('get_controller', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.sendAccountNumber = function() {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "first.php",
            data: {
                accountnumber: $scope.accountnumber
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }

        });

        /* Check whether the HTTP Request is successful or not. */
        request.success(function(data) {
            console.log("Account Number " + data + " Sent to first.php");
        });
    }


    $scope.geValues = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'second.php'
        }).success(function(data) {
            $scope.post = data;
            $scope.personDetails = Employee;
        })
    },
});
```

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39717293/6608101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your next function call in the promise of the first call in the following way:

```
    //First function
    $scope.firstFunction = function(){
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'first.php',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
          data: data
        }).then(
            function (response) {
                var data = response.data;
                $scope.secondFunction(data);
                // not relevant
            }, function (error) {
                var data = error.data;
                // not relevant
        });
    }
   //Second function
    $scope.secondFunction = function(data)
    {
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'second.php',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
          data: data
        }).then(
            function (response) {
                var newData = response.data;
                // not relevant
            }, function (error) {
                var newData = error.data;
                // not relevant
        });
    }
```

And call a one function `firstFunction()` on button click only.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="firstFunction();" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

FYI,

- I would recommend to use `ng-submit()` event for `form` to submit the form data rather then submitting by submit event of your form.
- And one more thing, why would you request two ajax calls ?
  You can do both the server side operations in single call only.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks !! Here in my case I have to do POST method for the first.php and GET method for the second.php will this work

Comment: You just need to change your Ajax Params as per your need.

Comment: Is everything ok ?

Comment: Hi I need to send the session from first.php to second.php and then I need to display the value from second.php

Do I need to use 2 POST action(one for sending input field to first.php and another from first.php to second.php)  and 1 GET(for getting values from second.php) action?

Comment: Yeah I tried I am able to show values from first.php in console log but not working for second.php

Comment: what's the issue ? Are you able to call second call from first success ? Can you create jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry I wont be able to jsfiddle due to security concern, But can u please let me know DO i need to create 2 POST and 1 GET or 1 POST and 1 GET
Because 1 POST and 1 GET didnt work for me

Comment: I think you can do everything in one ajax call.. Get the response from first ajax call and based on the do everything on php side, and then send t final response to angular .

Comment: Yeah I am able to call second call successfully but its not taking value from first.php
I am just using include first.php in second.php

Comment: Did you check your using post method in second call, try to check every param are proper or not, try to follow a way what I've suggested call inside a first call.